# Continuity of infimum argument

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: [0,1]^2 \mapsto \mathbb R$ is continuous. Let
$$
\underline{y}(x)\equiv \inf \{y\in [0,1]: f(x,y)\geq 0\}.
$$
There is $y_0\in(0,1)$ such that
$$f(0,y_0)= 0,$$

$$f(0,y)< 0 \quad \forall y\neq y_0.$$

Moreover,
$$
f(x,y_0) > 0 \quad \forall x\in (0,1].
$$

*I hope to find out: is it true that $\underline{y}(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$?*

*If not, what extra conditions may imply this?*

Thank you.

---

I am tempted to answer yes, and I imagine a proof may work along this line:

By the definition of $\underline{y}(x)$, as long as $\underline{y}(x)\in(0,1)$,
$$
f(x,\underline{y}(x))=0.
$$
Then I want to use some version of the Implicit Function Theorem to argue the continuity of $\underline{y}(x)$.

Two difficulties I encounter are:

- How to argue $y(x)\in (0,1)$ for $x$ in a neighbourhood of $0$?
- To use the Implicit Function Theorem (without differentiability) to argue the continuity of $\underline{y}(x)$ at $x=0$, it seems I need $f(x,\cdot)$ to be a one-to-one mapping for $(x,y)$ in a neighbourhood of $(0,y_0)$, which I do not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea is to use the compactness of the domain $[0,1]^2$ (which is necessary for the claim to work). From what you stated, we have $\underline{y}(0)=y_0$ and $\underline{y}(x) < y_0$ for $x \in (0,1]$.

What we will show is that, given some $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$f(x,y) < 0\; \forall x \in [0,\delta], \forall y \in [0, y_0-\epsilon]. \label{eq1} \tag{1}$$

This means $\forall x \in [0,\delta]: \underline{y}(x) \ge y_0 - \epsilon$ and with the above $\underline{y}(x) < y_0$ for $x \in (0,1]$ that means $\underline{y}(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

So let's fix some $\epsilon > 0$ now. We know that $f(0,y) < 0$ for $y \in [0,y_0-\epsilon]$. Since $y$ varies over a compact interval and $f(0,y)$ is continuous, it takes a maximum value $M < 0$ there. So we actually have $f(0,y) \le M < 0\; \forall y \in [0,y_0-\epsilon]$.

Since $f(x,y)$ is continuous, for each $y \in [0,y_0-\epsilon]$ we can find a small $\delta_y > 0$ such that in the rectangular neighborhood $[0, \delta_y] \times [y-\delta_y, y +\delta_y]$ of $(0,y)$ we still have $f(x,y) < 0$.

That's a $\delta_y$ for each $y \in [0,y_0-\epsilon]$, so uncountably many and the infimum of the $\delta_y$ is likely $0$. But note that the set of open intervals $(y-\delta_y, y +\delta_y)$ completely covers the compact interval $[0,y_0-\epsilon]$ (because each number in the latter is the center point of a former one).

By using compactness, we know we can pick a finite set of those intervals, centered around $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$ that still covers the complete interval $[0,y_0-\epsilon]$, with corresponding $\delta_{y_1},\ldots,\delta_{y_n}$.

Now we can choose our $\delta$ from \eqref{eq1} as

$$\delta = \min\{\delta_{y_1},\ldots,\delta_{y_n}\} > 0.$$

As a minimum of a finite number of positve values it is also positive! To check that \eqref{eq1} holds, lets select any $x \in [0,\delta], y \in [0, y_0-\epsilon]$. Then $y$ lies in one of the above constructed intervals, say the one centered around $y_k$. By construction, we know that for any $(a,b)$ inside $[0, \delta_{y_k}] \times [y_k-\delta_{y_k}, y_k +\delta_{y_k}]$ we have $f(a,b) < 0$.

We know that $y \in [y_k-\delta_{y_k}, y_k +\delta_{y_k}]$, because we chose $k$ such that this is true. $x \in [0,\delta]$ implies $0 \le x \le \delta \le \delta_k$ (by definition of $\delta$), hence $x \in [0, \delta_k]$. That means we have $(x,y) \in [0, \delta_{y_k}] \times [y_k-\delta_{y_k}, y_k +\delta_{y_k}]$ and so $f(x,y) < 0$, which is \eqref{eq1}.

This concludes the proof.

To summarize, "a little bit below" the point $y_0$ starts a compact interval  with all negative $f(0,y)$ values. Since the interval is compact and $f$ continuous, $f(0,y)$ cannot get "arbitrarily close" to $0$ there, so there is a "gap to 0". Again due to contuinuity of $f$, that "gap" can be extended a little bit into $x \in [0, \delta_y]$. Due to compactness of $[0, y_0-\epsilon]$, there is a finite list of intervals covering the whole $[0, y_0-\epsilon]$, and we can finally extend the "gap to 0" towards all $x$ in a small neighborhood of $0$, namely $[0,\delta]$, where the $\delta$ is now independent of $y$.